# Xvfb & Docker - cannot open display

Tags: firefox, docker, dockerfile, xvfb

I need to run XVFB and docker with firefox but can't get them to work together

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM abevoelker/ruby:latest # based on ubuntu
ENV TERM linux
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y .....

ENV DISPLAY :99

# Install Xvfb init script
ADD xvfb_init /etc/init.d/xvfb # default xvfb init.d
RUN chmod a+x /etc/init.d/xvfb

CMD ["firefox"]
```

The error message I get from Firefox is

```
 Error: cannot open display: :99
```

Comment: what about `CMD["xvfb_run firefox"]`

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your help ! The problem is that the real idea behind this is to launch selenium webdriver with firefox, in a ruby program, therefore I can't use xvfb_run

Comment: I use xvfb_run exactly for that - `xvfb_run bundle exec cucumber --profile jenkins`

Comment: are you running in MacOS ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved this by writing a startup script which will:

1. start xvfb
2. start firefox

Executing the script via `CMD` allows the proper sequence of commands to run on container startup.

Dockerfile

```
...
ENV DISPLAY :99

ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod a+x /run.sh

CMD /run.sh
```

run.sh

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 640x480x8 -nolisten tcp &
firefox
```

Comment: why is putting it into its own script any different from your original Dockerfile ?

Comment: Docker has no service manager built-in, so the Xvfb startup script didn't have any effect in the initial example.


By moving it to a script, which is executed when the container starts (CMD), Xvfb is correctly launched in the container.

Comment: @baer could you elaborate more on that? Why is the script lunched correctly since there isn't still a service manager?

Comment: if you are getting `_XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.`  error or warning pass `-nolisten unix` to the command. `Xvfb :99 -screen 0 640x480x8 -nolisten tcp -nolisten unix`